# How to find the number of ways a number is written with summation of one or more prime numbers?

Tags: primes

How to find the number of ways a number **n** is written with summation of one or more prime numbers?
For example:
**n**=5, the way is ***2***. 5,(2+3). 
**n**=10, the way is ***4***. (2+2+2+2+2),(2+2+3+3),(2+3+5),(5+5).

1<=**n**<=1000

Comment: So you don't want to have a crack at this yourself then?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a coding service.

Comment: this is math and not even coding question :)

Comment: by the way - does 5+0 counts too? really?

Comment: and 5 = 2+3 = 3+2

Comment: @Drako 5=(2+3)=(3+2), here only one of these two should be taken.

Comment: @Bathsheba, I don't want the code of this problem, I only want the technique.

Comment: In which case you ought to ask this on the mathematics or algorithms sites.

Comment: technique is that you get all the primes that are less than n and test all the possible variations one by one, and count how many you got

Answer (score 0):

You might try searching for "prime partitions." Or you might be interested in [this post](https://programmingpraxis.com/2012/10/19/prime-partitions/) at my blog. I won't give the code because you said you don't want it.

Comment: Thanks, Bro. Your blog is really helpful.